# Getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com/atl/nova/pega/report/template/util/TemplateLoader.getDsmTemplatemap()Ljava/util/Map;

Tags: java, collections

As we tried with updating the library, but not able to resolve the runtime exception.Getting the exception in.

`public Map<String, DsmVelocityTemplate> getDsmTemplateMap() {
        return dsmTemplatemap;
    }`

Comment: You haven't posted any information that could lead to a solution. You probably have compiled against a different version of your library than what you are running against. But that's as much as I can say with the information that you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your capitalization is correct, as in your Exception, you appear to be calling `.getDsmTemplatemap()` when the actual function is `.getDsmTemplateMap()` with a capital 'M' in Map